# Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSourc[

Tags: spring

Ok log4j and servlet bugs have been fixed. Now I have the following problem:

`Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSourc`

my current `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <!--
  <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
  -->

 <!-- Register and setup my servlet xml files here -->

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>appStore</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value></param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appStore</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
   /WEB-INF/zang-file-service.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>

</web-app>
```

And the zang-file-service.xml is below:

```
<beans xmlns="ht..p://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="h..p://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       h..p://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       h..p://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
       h..p://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd">

 <!-- h..p://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd -->

 <!-- Config properties files -->

 <!-- Hibernate database stuff -->

 <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
   <list>
    <value>properties/jdbc.properties</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>


 <bean id="dataSource1"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSourc">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
  <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
  <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
  <property name="maxActive" value="${database.maxConnections}" />
 </bean>


 <!-- LocalSessionFactoryBean u need to put the hbm files in the WEB-INF/classes 
  root director -->

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"></property>
  <property name="mappingResources">
   <list>
    <value>FileObject.hbm.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>


 <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
  <property name="sessionsFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="fileDownload" class="com.kc.models.FileManipulator">
  <property name="dbTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"></property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

edit: here is my jdbc/properties file

```
# DB properties file

database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zangshop
database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.user=XXXX
database.password=XXXX
database.maxConnections=25
```

EDIT: Full error from tomcat

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSourc] for bean with name 'dataSource1' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/zang-file-service.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSourc
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4323)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4771)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:763)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:987)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1390)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:998)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:990)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:576)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSourc
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1664)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:385)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1138)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have missed the last letter in the class name. It should be:

```
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
```

In order to get some compile-time validation for spring configuration you can try the [SpringSource Tool Suite (STS)](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts)

Comment: doh!! thanks! its hard to write xml as their is no syntax errors or anything unlike when you write something in POJO, say if you type Strin it will complain imediatly of a typo

Comment: @jonney if an answer solves your problem, you are expected to mark it as accepted (tick below the vote counter)